# How to return JSX of iterated array with MUI TreeView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui, iteration

I have a iterated data from a api response like below:

```
{
 "title": "Measurements",
 "id": "597e4f0e-f9ec-4409-9631-df5847dd04d6",
 "entry": [
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "042af059-3e78-4e42-b4f5-437ae6a61572",
       "display": "A Folder"
     }
   },
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "62b1f93e-7dbb-4507-b9aa-47c3ff214221",
       "display": "B Folder"
     }
   },
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "94e06841-c8ab-4c6c-abd1-74e957771fe7",
       "display": "C Folder",
       "resourceType": "List"
     }
   }
 ]
},
{
 "title": "A Folder",
 "id": "042af059-3e78-4e42-b4f5-437ae6a61572",
 "entry": [
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "item id",
       "display": "A Sub Folder"
     }
   }
 ]
},
{
 "title": "B Folder",
 "id": "94e06841-c8ab-4c6c-abd1-74e957771fe7",
 "entry": [
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "item id",
       "display": "B Sub Folder"
     }
   }
 ]
},
{
 "title": "C Folder",
 "id": "62b1f93e-7dbb-4507-b9aa-47c3ff214221",
 "entry": [
   {
     "date": "2013-11-20T23:10:23+11:00",
     "item": {
       "id": "item id",
       "display": "C Sub Folder"
     }
   }
 ]
}
]
```

In this response, I fetch all of the tree actually. And I want to render them with using MUI TreeView component like in the image below:

[image: I need to show all the tree like this.]

The problem here is, I give the reference of sub folders in `"entry"` field. How can I render all the tree with using `"entry.item.id"` reference ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the api to change the shape?  My first impression is that it could be easier if the shape of the return data is already in a "Tree" shape.  Could the sub-folders be a child of the "Folder" objects?  If not, what is the criteria that a data objects "belongs" to another object?  The name?

Comment: @ckesplin I cannot change the shape of the response. Its a standart. In response, I fetch all of the tree. I have all data. Sub folders are given as a reference in entry array. For example, A,B,C folders are below the "Measurements" folder. I understand that from "entry" field of "Measurements". And I have all the info of A,B,C folders.